# Basic Grouping in jupyter lab

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run this code and I am getting attribute error. Can anyone help?

```
df_group_one = df_group_one.groupby(['drive-wheels'],as_index=False).mean()
df_group_one

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[50], line 1
----> 1 df_group_one = df_group_one.groupby(['drive-wheels'],as_index=False).mean()
      2 print(df_group_one)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

expected the code to group the df

Answer (score 0):

df_group_one is apparently a list and not a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: how do i resolve this please

Comment: If you want to use methods of a pandas.DataFrame you need to transform your data into one. Without knowledge how df_group_one looks like, it is imposdible to tell. Maybe you read pandas documentation.

Comment: To add to FordPrefect's great advice, this has nothing to do with JupyterLab. If you ran this code directly in your IDE or in a text script that you pointed Python at for execution, you'd have the same issue. Keep in mind JupyterLab can run a lot of languages in itself depending on the kernel you use. Your topic categories should be 'Pandas' and 'Python' and your title should not mention 'JupyterLab'. 'Pandas' in it's place would be more appropriate. You can indeed though mention in your post that you are running your code in JupyterLab for completeness, but here it is tangential.

Comment: @Wayne I edited the op with this regard, but it is pending.

Comment: Size of comments are limited or I would have added that the point of that is mutil-fold. Some of the reasons: 1) It more easily insures those knowledgeable see your question; 2) Helps you see what you should be searching around for before posting as, ideally, you shouldn't be posting questions & topics already covered here, and 3) It helps others having the same problem find a solution. Keep in mind that although you might think at this time helping others later is not important, several months from now you may end up treading the same ground & you'll be making it easier for your future self.

Comment: I don't understand why you are telling me this. I made a proposal for edit's of the opening post because of that. To improve the question to make it more concise and bring it into the right context.